# Postgresql error with Knex Adapter in KeystoneJS 5: 'Error: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined'

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, keystonejs

I am new to Postgresql (more familiar with Mongo) but our DevOps want me to transition a KeystoneJS project from Mongo to Postgresql.  I followed the [KeystoneJS instructions](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/adapter-knex/) and all went fine until I tried adding the ['atCreated' plugin](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/list-plugins/at-tracking), specifically the 'createdAtField' plugin, to get a created date in my list. I started getting DB errors, and, thinking that I needed to rebuild the database, I ran the KeystoneJS init script to drop the database and rebuild it.  Since then, I've gotten the following error:

```
  $ tsc && cross-env NODE_ENV=development DISABLE_LOGGING=true keystone --entry=tsout/index.js dev --port=4545
    ℹ Command: keystone dev --entry=tsout/index.js --port=4545
    ✔ Validated project entry file ./tsout/index.js
    ✔ Keystone server listening on port 4545
    ✔ Initialised Keystone instance
    ⠋ Connecting to databaseType "OEmbed" is missing a "__resolveType" resolver. Pass false into "resolverValidationOptions.requireResolversForResolveType" to disable this warning.
    setting up cron job
    ⠙ Connecting to database  knex:query select 1+1 as result undefined +0ms
    ⠹ Connecting to database  knex:query SHOW server_version; undefined +65ms
    ✖ Connecting to database
    Error: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
        at /Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/utils/dist/utils.cjs.dev.js:57:21
        at async executeDefaultServer (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/bin/utils.js:114:3) {
      errors: {
        KnexAdapter: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
            at /Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/adapter-knex/lib/adapter-knex.js:258:31
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at KnexListAdapter._postConnect (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/adapter-knex/lib/adapter-knex.js:257:24)
            at /Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/adapter-knex/lib/adapter-knex.js:73:19
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at KnexAdapter.postConnect (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/adapter-knex/lib/adapter-knex.js:72:38)
            at KnexAdapter.connect (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/adapter-knex/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/adapters/index.js:29:38)
            at async pReflect (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/p-reflect/index.js:5:17)
            at async Promise.all (index 0)
            at async executeDefaultServer (/Users/ranthony/Documents/projects/yaa-keystone/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/bin/utils.js:114:3)
      }
    }
```

The DB is obviously empty, but KeystoneJS allows you to set up a new database based on the current lists using

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
    name: PROJECT_NAME,
    adapter: new KnexAdapter({ dropDatabase: true })
});
```

I went back to a prior branch, hoping to undo the errors (except the dropped DB of course), but the error persists.

For what it's worth, these are the KeystoneJS versions I'm using:

```
"@keystonejs/adapter-knex": "^7.0.0",
"@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose": "^5.2.0",
    "@keystonejs/app-admin-ui": "^5.8.0",
    "@keystonejs/app-graphql": "^5.1.0",
    "@keystonejs/app-next": "^5.1.0",
    "@keystonejs/app-static": "^5.1.0",
    "@keystonejs/auth-password": "^5.1.0",
    "@keystonejs/field-content": "^5.4.0",
    "@keystonejs/fields": "^6.3.0",
    "@keystonejs/fields-markdown": "^5.1.0",
    "@keystonejs/fields-wysiwyg-tinymce": "^5.2.0",
    "@keystonejs/file-adapters": "^5.5.0",
    "@keystonejs/keystone": "^5.5.0",
    "@keystonejs/list-plugins": "^5.1.2",
    "@keystonejs/oembed-adapters": "^5.1.0",
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue today.

Answer (score 1):

Your knex adapter also needs the connection string:

```
const { KnexAdapter: Adapter } = require('@keystonejs/adapter-knex');

const adapterConfig = { knexOptions:{ 
                                     connection: 'postgres://<your-user>:<your-paswrd>@<your-host>:<your-port>/<your-db>' 
                                    },
                                    dropDatabase:true 
                      };
```

and then call the adapter when creating your keystone project

```
const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter(adapterConfig),
});
```